# Select columns in pandas dataframe by index (column) number

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I have been mainly an R user up until now, and I am now trying to get better with Python, so please keep that in mind as I may not be thinking in a pythonic way...

In any case, here it goes, I want to subset a pandas dataframe by column position, where I would select for instance, the first 2 columns, the the 4th column, and then the last two columns.

The code I used for that is as follows:

```
df01 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(10, 10)),
                columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i','j'])
df01.iloc[:,list(range(0,2)) + list([3]) + list(range(-3,-1))]
```

I am doing the subsetting by essentially creating 3 lists with the columns I want, but I am thinking there must be a better way to do this as this appears to me as too cumbersome. In R I could just do a simple:

```
df01[c(1:2,4,9:10)]
```

Again, this may be just the way it is, but given my status as a python "newbie', Im interested to know if there is a better more concise way.

Thanks,

Comment: Use `df.iloc[:,np.r_[1:2,4,9:10]]`. where np is `import numpy as np`

Comment: Yeap!!! `np.r_` did the trick and is what I was looking for... Thanks @SandeepKadapa

Answer (score 8):

Remember that Python is zero indexed. Here you have ten columns but the max index will be nine. You can do this in `pandas` with the following:

```
df01.iloc[:, [0,1,3,8,9]]

   a  b  d  i  j
0  6  0  9  9  0
1  7  9  9  4  4
2  1  3  4  0  4
3  4  6  1  7  0
4  4  6  3  1  2
5  5  6  2  9  1
6  0  6  6  6  2
7  8  2  0  5  5
8  4  7  5  8  4
9  2  3  6  2  9
```